# How to report an issue with the entrance when Maps never thinks I have arrived

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps / Directions has this neat feature where after you reach your destination it asks you if it routed you to a convenient or proper entrance.  This is very nice because sometimes when there is a cluster of businesses it doesn't know the proper way to route you to the building you are going to and you can help out by telling Google where it should have had you enter.

However, there is one office building I frequent that it keeps wanting me to head about 500 feet further down the road.  The would put me right in front of the building on a busy street, whereas the correct entrance is to turn right and go into a parking lot behind the building.  Unfortunately I have not figured out how to report this to the mapping program, because even once I go into the entrance it still is telling me to keep going.  If I exit navigation it never asks how it did!  I used to remember an option to tell it you want to walk the rest of the way but I don't see that any more and don't know if it would help.

Short of going for a long walking detour (which I never have time for), how can I tell Google that I have reached my destination so it can get my feedback on how to make directions better?

Update: I tried walking in the building itself to try to get closer to where it wants me to go while I was waiting for an appointment, but I am not actually getting a signal.  I'm not really sure if it's even possible to get to where Maps wants me to go without walking outside around the whole building, which is probably around 1000 feet.

Comment: I think this question is about the Android app instead of the web app. If this is right the question is off-topic on this site but could be on-topic on [android.se].

Comment: Usually in such cases the parking lot has a different address as it is connected to a different street. I don't think that Google would change the routing behavior in your case as the routing is correct - you want to be routed to the building. If you want to go to the parking lot this is a different destination.